# "retryDelay" when nodejs uses GetItem in dynamodb

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I'm doing a login in my app, I was using Dynamodb local and I worked fine, but when I tried to connect to dynamodb in AWS i got the error:

```
{ 
 "retryDelay": 21.203729590174113 }
}
```

My code to connect is the next:

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.update({endpoint: "https://dynamodb.us-east-2.amazonaws.com", region: "us-east-2"});
var credentials = new AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials({profile: 'default'});
AWS.config.credentials = credentials;

var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient(credentials);

//Verifica la exitencia de un usuario
exports.init_session = function(req, res) {
  console.log('Iniciando consulta con ' + req.body.user);
  var params = {
      TableName: "usuarios",
      Key:{
          "user": req.body.user
      },
       "ProjectionExpression": "pass"
  };
  docClient.get(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
          console.error("Unable to read item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
          res.send("Unable to read item. Error JSON:" + JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
      } else {
        if(JSON.stringify(data) != '{}'){  //si el usuario existe
            if( req.body.pass != data.Item.pass){ //Si la contraseña es incorrecta
                res.send('Contraseña inválida');
            }else{
            req.session.user = req.body.user;
            res.redirect('/');
          }
        }else {
            res.send('No existe el usuario');
        }
      }
  });
};
```

When I do the same request in a single script it works fine.

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

AWS.config.update({endpoint: "https://dynamodb.us-east-2.amazonaws.com", region: "us-east-2"});
var credentials = new AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials({profile: 'default'});
AWS.config.credentials = credentials;

var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()

var params = {
    TableName: "usuarios",
    Key:{
        "user": "user2"
    }
};

docClient.get(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to read item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("GetItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
});
```

I through the problem was req.body.user, but in the console.log shows up and string. What is the problem, why does this show up {"retryDelay": random_number }?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little embarrassing, my error was this line.

```
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient(credentials);
```

I delete the var credentials and it works fine.

```
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
```

Answer (score 1):

[The AWS config is part of the core AWS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Config.html)

When you are running locally your default config will probably be getting loaded from a [profile file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-multiple-profiles.html) at

```
~/.aws/config
```

Im not quite sure where your config is being loaded from in other environments, but I can see you are updating your config (`AWS.config.update`) rather than creating a new one, which would look something like:

```
var config = new AWS.Config({
  accessKeyId: 'AKID', secretAccessKey: 'SECRET', region: 'us-west-2'
});
```